# Graphviz: Left-Right subgraphs, Left-Right inside subgraphs

Tags: visualization, graphviz, dot, subgraph

What I am trying to achieve is clusters (subgraphs) side by side while their content is also side by side as demonstrated in this image:

[image: Clusters side by side]

but all I can make is the top-bottom behavior of the subgraphs as in this image:

[image: Clusters top-bottom]

I am aware that this is an open issue ([Allow different rankdir for subgraph cluster](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/887))

But I also saw some workarounds for similar issues ( i.e. [top-down subgraphs, left-right inside subgraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777722/top-down-subgraphs-left-right-inside-subgraphs), [GraphViz - How to have a subgraph be left-to-right when main graph is top-to-bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554635/graphviz-how-to-have-a-subgraph-be-left-to-right-when-main-graph-is-top-to-bot))

Based on the workarounds I could get a diagonal representation:

[image: diagonal representation]

but not the desired one.

this is my .Dot file:

```
    digraph {
    node [shape=plain]
    rankdir=LR;

  subgraph cluster_Asia { 
        label = "Asia";

        China [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>China</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Shanghai">Shanghai</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Beijing">Beijing</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Chongqing">Chongqing</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Tianjin">Tianjin</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
          India [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>India</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="NewDelhi">NewDelhi</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Mumbai">Mumbai</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Bangalore">Bangalore</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Ahmadabad">Ahmadabad</td></tr>
        </table>>];

        Thailand [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Thailand</i></td></tr>  
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Bangkok">Bangkok</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="ChiangRai">ChiangRai</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
        Nepal [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Nepal</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Kathmandu">Kathmandu</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Birgunj">Birgunj</td></tr>
        </table>>];
          
        China:Shanghai->Thailand:Bangkok[color="blue", style=solid ]
        China:Beijing->Nepal:Kathmandu[color="blue", style=solid ]
        China:Tianjin->India:NewDelhi[color="blue",style=solid ]
        China:Chongqing->India:Ahmadabad[color="blue", style=solid ]
        India:Ahmadabad->India:Mumbai[color="blue", style=solid ]
}

  subgraph cluster_Europe {
        label = "Europe"; 

        Spain [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Spain</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Madrid">Madrid</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Malaga">Malaga</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Barcelona">Barcelona</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Valencia">Valencia</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
        Netherlands [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Netherlands</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Rotterdam">Rotterdam</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Dokkum">Dokkum</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
        Italy [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Italy</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Rome">Rome</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Venice">Venice</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Milan">Milan</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
        France [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>France</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Paris">Paris</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Nice">Nice</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Marseille">Marseille</td></tr>
        </table>>];

        Spain:Madrid->Netherlands:Dokkum[ color="blue",style=solid ]
        Spain:Barcelona->Italy:Milan[ color="blue",style=solid ]
        Spain:Malaga->Netherlands:Amsterdam[color="blue", style=solid ]
        Spain:Valencia->France:Nice[color="blue", style=solid ]
}


    // {  rank=same;
        // 00 [style=invis];
        // 01 [style=invis];
        // 00 -> 01 [constraint=false,style=invis];
    // }

     // 00 -> Spain [style=invis];
     // 01 -> China [style=invis];
    
   // Spain -> China [ style=invis];
}
```

Notice that the diagonal code is commented out at the bottom of the code scope.

**My question**:

How can I change my code to get a result as similar as possible to the first image?

Comment: You probably have to play a bit with the rankdir, a good start might be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466188/subgraphs-horizontal-and-its-nodes-vertical-aligned  Note with Bangkok there is attribute `tyle` instead of `style`. It is nice to know that Rome is now the capital of Italy and France ( :-)) )

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will check this link too, as for Paris and the typo - I've fixed it in the code but not in the images. Thanks for pointing this out 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Albert I've found the solution:

[image: Desired output]

This is the code:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=plain]
    rankdir=LR;

subgraph cluster_Asia { 
    label = "Asia";

    China [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr><td><i>China</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Shanghai">Shanghai</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Beijing">Beijing</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Chongqing">Chongqing</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Tianjin">Tianjin</td></tr>
    </table>>];
    
      India [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr><td><i>India</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="NewDelhi">NewDelhi</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Mumbai">Mumbai</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Bangalore">Bangalore</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Ahmadabad">Ahmadabad</td></tr>
    </table>>];

    Thailand [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr><td><i>Thailand</i></td></tr>  
      <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Bangkok">Bangkok</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="ChiangRai">ChiangRai</td></tr>
    </table>>];
    
    Nepal [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr><td><i>Nepal</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Kathmandu">Kathmandu</td></tr>
      <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Birgunj">Birgunj</td></tr>
    </table>>];
      
    China:Shanghai->Thailand:Bangkok[color="blue", tyle=solid ]
    China:Beijing->Nepal:Kathmandu[color="blue", style=solid ]
    China:Tianjin->India:NewDelhi[color="blue",style=solid ]
    China:Chongqing->India:Ahmadabad[color="blue", style=solid ]
    India:Ahmadabad->India:Mumbai[color="blue", style=solid ]
}


  
  subgraph cluster_Europe {
        label = "Europe"; 

        Spain [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Spain</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Madrid">Madrid</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Malaga">Malaga</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Barcelona">Barcelona</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Valencia">Valencia</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
        Netherlands [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Netherlands</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Rotterdam">Rotterdam</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Dokkum">Dokkum</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
        Italy [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>Italy</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Rome">Rome</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Venice">Venice</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Milan">Milan</td></tr>
        </table>>];
        
        France [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><i>France</i></td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="yellow" port="Paris">Paris</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Nice">Nice</td></tr>
          <tr><td bgcolor="white" port="Marseille">Marseille</td></tr>
        </table>>];

        Spain:Madrid->Netherlands:Dokkum[ color="blue",style=solid ]
        Spain:Barcelona->Italy:Milan[ color="blue",style=solid ]
        Spain:Malaga->Netherlands:Amsterdam[color="blue", style=solid ]
        Spain:Valencia->France:Nice[color="blue", style=solid ]
}

    {  
      00 [style=invis];
      01 [style=invis];
      02 [style=invis];
      03 [style=invis];
      00 -> 01 -> 02 -> 03 [style=invis];

      00 -> Spain [style=invis];
      01 -> Netherlands [style=invis];
      01 -> Italy [style=invis];
      01 -> France [style=invis];
      02 -> China [style=invis];
      03 -> Nepal [style=invis];
      03 -> Thailand [style=invis];
      03 -> India [style=invis];
    
    Spain -> China [ style=invis];
    }
}
```

The last scope is fixing the layout.